# Why is .then not a function?

Tags: angularjs

**service.js**

```
.factory('EventService', function ($http, $cordovaSQLite) {
    return {
        //some code here..
        populateData: function (data) {
            var items = [];
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                items.push(data[i]);
            }
            return items;
        }
    }
})
```

**controller.js**

```
.controller('NearCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $cordovaSQLite, EventService) {
    EventService.getDataFromDB().then(function (result) {
        if (result.length > 0) {
            EventService.populateData(result).then(function (items) {
                $scope.items = items;
            })
        } else {
            EventService.getDataFromApi().then(function () {
                EventService.getDataFromDB().then(function (result) {
                    EventService.populateData(result).then(function (items) {
                        $scope.items = items;
                    })
                })
            })
        }
    });
})
```

When I'm trying to run this code, I get "TypeError: EventService.populateData(...).then is not a function".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `populateData` does not return a promise, you dont get `then` attached to everything by default. it is a part of promise object. You just have to do `$scope.items = EventService.populateData(result)`

Answer (score 31):

that service needs to return a promise, not returning the items

```
populateData: function(data) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var items = [];
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        items.push(data[i]);
    }
    deferred.resolve(items);
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

you might not need this though since you could do

```
var items = EventService.populateData(result);
//Do something with items here
```

usually promises are used if you're doing something asynchronously. Like calling an API and waiting for a response. In those cases, the response might take seconds to finish THEN the .then function gets called. in your case if you make that function a promise it will be called almost immediately

EDIT: Here's the link to $q Documentation [AngularJS: API: $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Answer (score 5):

Return something that has a promise or just change your calling code:

```
populateData: return $http.get("www");
```

or

```
EventService.getDataFromApi().then(function () {
    EventService.getDataFromDB().then(function (result) {
        var response = EventService.populateData(result);
        $scope.items = response;
    });
});
```

Answer (score -9):

I have same problem, My device is m1 Mac, I fixed it with npm replace yarn to start