# AngularJS .then is not a function()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Why I get this error when calling .then on a promise?

> vm.submitPromise(...).then is not a function

A simplified version of my code is this:

```
    var submitPromise = function($q) {
      return function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        //$scope.ngSubmitFunction();    

        // simulated async function
        $timeout(function() {
          deferred.resolve('data received!')
        }, 2000);
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    }

    function ngSubmit($form) {
      vm.submitDisabled = true;
      submitPromise().then(function() {
          vm.submitDisabled = false;
      });
    };
```

This is part from a directive managing forms. The purpose is for the Submit button to call a function that may have one or more async calls, and I need to wait for them to finish before enabling the submit button again.

Almost everywhere I read this happens when the function doesn't return a promise, but mine does (I believe). Doesn't it? what am I missing. I'm trying to debugg with a simulated async function $timeout and a .resolve in there (can be seen on the code) but I get the same error.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707822/why-then-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 2):

`submitPromise` is returning a function, which in turn returns a promise, but you are not invoking the function. Given the signature of that method, you would need to use it like so:

```
function ngSubmit($form) {
  vm.submitDisabled = true
  submitPromise()().then(function () {
    vm.submitDsabled = false
  })
}
```

You probably wanted to do this instead:

```
var submitPromise = function($q) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  //$scope.ngSubmitFunction();    

  // simulated async function
  $timeout(function() {
    deferred.resolve('data received!')
  }, 2000);
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Note the deferred pattern is deprecated and `$q` (along with the native `Promise` implementation in your browser) suggest a more constructor-based pattern instead:

```
function submitPromise($q) {
  return $q(function (resolve) {
    $timeout(function() {
      resolve()
    }, 2000)
  })
}
```

The reason for this is mainly because then your use of `$q` matches the ES6 spec, and also means you aren't imperatively managing the promise itself (which can lead to authoring mistakes).

Comment: Thanks! that was definitely the problem. Thought there was also another error on my code that you reproduced in yours. Passing $q as an argument for the submitPromise function made $q undefined when calling the function. **function submitPromise() {..code..}** is the correct declaration.

Comment: $q would only be undefined if you didn't pass $q to the function invocation, ie you didn't call it like `submitPromise($q)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a function where as you need to return a promise.

```
var submitPromise = function($q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    // simulated async function
    $timeout(function() {
      deferred.resolve('data received!')
    }, 2000);
    return deferred.promise;      
}
```

*OR*, You need to invoke the returned function like

```
function ngSubmit($form) {
    vm.submitDisabled = true
        submitPromise()().then(function () {
        vm.submitDsabled = false
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`submitPromise` returns a function. Hence, you need to execute it

Try following

```
 function ngSubmit($form) {
      vm.submitDisabled = true;
      submitPromise()().then(function() {
          vm.submitDisabled = false;
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

not your question - your function just return function instead of promise but...

```
var submitPromise = function(){
    return $timeout(function(){
         return data;
    }, 2000);
};
```

this is the right way of writing your example